# Find the similarity transformation (geometry)

Tags: geometry, transformation

i have problems in the following task:

Find a similarity transformation $F:\mathbb{R}²\rightarrow \mathbb{R}²$ so that

- $F(1,1)=(2,0)$
- $F(1,3)=(2,1)$
- $F(3,1)=(1,0)$

I started by using the definition of a similarity transformation: $F(x)=\lambda\cdot f(x)+q$. But i have no idea to go further. Can anybody help me?

Comment: In your formula, if $x$ is a 2x1 matrix, then $\lambda$ is a 2x2 matrix and $q$ is a 2x1 matrix. $\lambda$ is a matrix that produces rotation and scaling and $q$ is a matrix that produces translation and scaling. Adopt $f(x)=x$, $x$ is the coordinates matrix.